# What is wrong with this sentence? "Of all the places he vacationed, Ian's favorite is the time when him and his best friend went to Virginia."

Tags: errors

> **Of all the places he vacationed, Ian's favorite is the time when him and his best friend went to Virginia.**

I just was asked in an exam to identify the error in this sentence.
I think the error is "is". Shouldn't it be phrased in the past tense or is it still grammatically correct?

The reason I ask is because one of the five answer choices was: correct as it is.
 I remember the question but not all the five choices I had to choose form.

I do remember one more, where they underlined "OF" as the error to the sentence.

I'd appreciate any feed back.

Comment: So you think "him went to Virginia" is correct?

Comment: (But of course the sentence also has a serious semantic problem.)

Comment: (In fact, the sentence is very poorly written from several standpoints.  Who created this test?)

Comment: Thanks guys, so "Him" is the error right?  Also am I correct in saying that by taking out the conjunction "and his best friend" is the best way to see if the sentence doesn't' makes sense?

Comment: "*So 'Him' is the error right?*" The **exam** is the error. It is bugged in supposing that there is only one problem with the sentence. The grammar problem of using *him* is the least important problem. @curious-proofreader already pointed to a more important (though not grammatical) problem.

Comment: @IanSimons - Within the question as presented, using "him" instead of "he" is the worst of the problems. So yes, "him" is the error. But there are others, most notably the confusion of place (of all the places) with time (the time he and his best friend). A time is not a place, so "the time he and etc" cannot be one of the places he visited, let alone a favorite. And yes, simplifying to just the one subject shows the problem. After all. he went to Virginia - him didn't.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on what @WhatRoughBeast is referring to about  "the time he and etc"  because I'm a little confused since I know a time is not a place but the place is Virginia.

Comment: Playing with order, this is what the sentence says: The Virginia *time* is Ian's favorite *place* to recall.  Virginia is a place, that vacation period is a time, but they do not equate.  In spoken English, we do this sort of sloppiness, and friends forgive.  What's done is done.  But in writing, standards are higher, because we can correct it.

Answer (score 2):

In my mind there are four errors:

1. The use of "him" in places of "he" in "him... went to Virginia" is clearly an error (as pointed out).
2. The other issue making this odd sentence read so badly is the disagreement between "**places** he vacationed" and "the **time** when".
3. In addition, there is a tense/time disagreement between "vacation**ed**" (past) and "**is** the time when" (present).

So, if rewritten as follows, it is improved:

> Of all the times he vacationed, Ian's favorite was the time when he and his best friend went to Virginia.
>
> OR
>
> Of all the places he vacationed, Ian's favorite was Virginia where he went with his best friend.

4. More controversially though, from my perspective as an Australian English speaker, it's the use of the verb "vacationed" that grates on my ear as a fourth error.  Do you guys really say, "I *vacationed* New York last week." ?

Even if I substitute "holidayed" (the equivalent verb in UK and Aus English for "vacationed") then I still feel like a preposition is missing. For example, in my version of English, it must be, "I holidayed in Singapore before starting the job in London." and could never be, "I holidayed Singapore before starting the job in London". "Holidaying" is something that is done *at* or *in* a location, not something that is done *to* the location. I am assuming this would be the same with "vacationed" in US usage, but you are welcome to correct me if I am wrong.

So this is where I end up:

> Of all the places he had vacationed in, Ian's favorite was Virginia where he went with his best friend.

Comment: No, we do not say "I vacationed New York", but we do allow for elided prepositions in this sort of construction:  "of all the places I've vacationed" (with no *in*) is just as normal as "of all the places I've been" (with no *to*).

Comment: Your reason (3) is not valid. "Of all the places where he holidayed, Virginia *is* his favourite" -- he has a current favourite from all the places in the past.

Comment: @Hellion Good differentiating.

Comment: @Hellion Yes I understand and agree. I had not considered elision.